# onCreateView() never runs (Trying to use ViewPager for screen slides)

Tags: android, android-viewpager

My goal is to use ViewPager (like [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)) to let user slide through 5 different pages (a tutorial) before my MainActivity starts...

I've downloaded Animations.zip from the link above and its almost what I need, except for supporting older versions (what I managed by changing android.app references to android.support.v4.app) and using totally different layouts instead of using the same view like in the example...

My code compiles and runs, but on the phone's screen I can't see the slides changing. The action bar appears, its buttons are working fine, and I can even see that blue glow when I reach the first/last page and try to slide again... I guess android is generating default layouts for some reason.

While debugging, I've noticed that **onCreateView() inside the fragment never runs**. Any idea why? My code is as below:

**como_usar_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
          android:id="@+id/texto_como_usar_fragment"
          android:padding="16dp"
          android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="aglaglalglaglalgalgalglag"
          android:textColor="@color/branco"
        />
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
    />
```

**ComoUsarFragment.java**

```
public class ComoUsarFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The argument key for the page number this fragment represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";

/**
 * The fragment's page number, which is set to the argument value for {@link #ARG_PAGE}.
 */
private int mPageNumber;

/**
 * Factory method for this fragment class. Constructs a new fragment for the given page number.
 */
public static Fragment create(int pageNumber) {
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public ComoUsarFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //this is an attempt to set different views for each page, you'll see I dont use this piece of code yet
    int pagina;
    switch (mPageNumber){
        case 0: pagina = R.layout.como_usar0;
            break;

        case 1: pagina = R.layout.como_usar1;
            break;

        case 2: pagina = R.layout.como_usar2;
            break;

        default: pagina = R.layout.como_usar_fragment;
            break;
    }


    // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.como_usar_fragment, container, false);

    // Set the title view to show the page number.
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("aaaaa "+mPageNumber);

    return rootView;
}

/**
 * Returns the page number represented by this fragment object.
 */
public int getPageNumber() {
    return mPageNumber;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a standard fragment instead of your own subclass

```
public static Fragment create(int pageNumber) {
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    ...
```

should be

```
public static Fragment create(int pageNumber) {
    Fragment fragment = new ComoUsarFragment();
    ...
```

Comment: I've changed it, now I'm getting `10-16 11:02:25.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at br.com.maisapp.ComoUsarFragment.onCreateView(ComoUsarFragment.java:72)`

Comment: Well that is a different issue. Check what is null at line 72 and resolve it. If you cannot, you should post a new question with your code and logcat.

Comment: I commented the line in wich I was trying to change the textview inside como_usar_fragment.xml and it worked! I was looking for this text1 ID that doesn't exists at my layout... For those who check my code above, it has an error with the scrollview (it can host only one child). Thanks!